# What is the 'go' point for organ donation from a registered organ donor?

Tags: medical, death

Assuming a patient is a registered organ donor, at what point their organs can be legally transplanted? Brain death? Clinical death?

Answer (score 1):

> "Brain death is the total and irreversible loss of all brain function
> and the circumstance under which the donation of vital organs most
> commonly takes place." (http://www.donorrecovery.org/learn/understanding-brain-death/)

They are donated when brain death occurs, since clinical death, can be reversable (restarting the heart).

> clinical death is the medical term for cessation of blood circulation and breathing, the two necessary criteria to sustain life. This is what you call cardiopulmonary arrest, a period when a person’s heartbeat and breathing stop but can still be revived if early medical attention is given. (https://www.nursebuff.com/clinical-death-versus-brain-death-which-comes-first/)
>
> This is when the doctor will formally or legally declare that the person is dead as the neurological damage to the person is really impossible to reverse. (https://www.nursebuff.com/clinical-death-versus-brain-death-which-comes-first/)

They aren't officaly condidered death at clinical death, only brain death, because with medical help they could come back to life, and you need to make sure someone is dead before you remove all their organs.